# A logarithmic constraint using fmincon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I want to minimize the following minimization problem using `fmincon` in MATLAB

[image]

The code below (Strategy 1) that I have written solves the problem when I replace the logarithmic (nonlinear) constraint by the linear constraint `sum(x) = 5`. So how can I change it to introduce the logarithmic constraint? I am blocked here.

**MATLAB CODE (Strategy 1):**

```
x0 = zeros(3,1);
Sigma = rand(3,3); %take any matrix

Obj_func = @(x) sqrt(x' * Sigma * x);

options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point', 'MaxFunctionEvaluations', 1e100);

[x, FVAL, EXITFLAG, OUTPUT] = fmincon(Obj_func, x0, [], [], ones(1,3), 5, zeros(3,1), inf(3,1), [], options);
```

Another way to do it (see [This reference](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-constraints.html)) can be as below but I am sure if I am correct. (I need help).

**MATLAB CODE (Strategy 2):**

```
fun = @(x)sqrt(x' * Sigma * x);

nonlcon = @my_function;
x0 = [0 0 0]';
A = []; % No other constraints
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
lb = zeros(3,1);
ub = inf(3,1);
w = fmincon(fun, x0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub, nonlcon)


function [const,ceq] = my_function(x)
const(1) = 5 - sum(log(x));
ceq = [];
end
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: If you're looking for a starting point, that starting point is a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+fmincon), not [asking on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I edited my question. Hope you can help since at your profile you have written that you are very strong in matlab:)

Comment: What is the problem with your second strategy? Did you get an error?

Comment: I added `rng(123);` before the definition of `Sigma` and ran Strategy 2 above and got `w = [5.1832; 5.2581; 5.4455]` (using R2019a). I'm also curious to know what the problem seems to be...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I don't get any error with the Strategy 2, but I just want to know if what I have written in Strategy 2 seems correct..

Comment: @Vicky Thanks for your comment. I don't get any error but are you sure that what you obtained is really the right answer that should be? I am just asking to know if my code is written correctly (logically correct) or there is some mistakes... Thanks.

Comment: I guess your implementation looks fine. You could adapt your code to another nonlinear optimization problem whose solution you already know and check if the result is as expected, if you wanted to be sure. BTW: since SO tends to be somewhat problem-driven, in situations like this, where you have a program that seems to be working correctly, you may want to see what the people at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have to say about it.

Comment: @Vicky Thank you for your reply. Ah great I didn't know about Code Review! Thanks